# Autolayout and UIScrollview and Child View Controller issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, autolayout

In my app I have an embedded child view controller into which at runtime I have to add one or more "Editor UIView"s based on data coming in from the server. I could model each "Editor" as a complete UIViewController in a xib file and add it at run time. The parent of the "Editor" has some items of its own (like titles and a couple of buttons) so I've tried to build a layered approach using a single child UIViewController and loading the "Editors" into its UIScrollview on the fly. However I can't get Autolayout to cooperate. This diagram shows the basic arrangement.
[image]

The problems start with just having the "Content View" embedded in the UIScrollview. I can get the content view to work OK with the scrollview. When I add the editor view and add runtime constraints to the content view, I get multiple auto layout complaints plus the scroll view content size is 0,0 so I am clearly not getting what I need.

Any ideas on how to approach this? I could always simply duplicate the child controller's extra items for each editor but it would be nice to have this work in this layered fashion.

Note I did this first with a UITableViewController where each editor is a UITableViewCell and that auto layout liked but I wanted to see if I could do it without the table. Maybe I will go back to that.

Added these at runtime:

```
_editor = [self editorForDataType];
[_contentView addSubview:_editor];

NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_editor
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:0
                                                                     toItem:self.contentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];
[self.contentView addConstraint:leftConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_editor
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                   relatedBy:0
                                                                      toItem:self.contentView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0];
[self.contentView addConstraint:rightConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_editor
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:0
                                                                     toItem:self.contentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];
[self.contentView addConstraint:topConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_editor
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                   relatedBy:0
                                                                      toItem:self.contentView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0];
[self.contentView addConstraint:bottomConstraint];
```

Comment: Did you set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO for your _editor views?

Comment: Yes, although it appears to be NO by default.

Comment: In what method did you add the constraints?  `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Yes viewDidLoad. I was wondering if this might be too early.

Answer (score 1):

In the end the key to what I needed was the follow set of constraints, plus adding the constraints for the editor view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and saving a property for the content view Height.

In `viewDidLoad` I set the height property to the height of the editor view. Now it works great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your last two constraints are incorrect. You have leading to top and trailing to bottom, those should be top to top and bottom to bottom. However, those constraints probably aren't what you want. If it's the first editor view, you probably want the top constraint to the content view and a height constraint. For any subsequent ones, you should pin the top to the editor view above it, rather than the content view.

Comment: I moved the constraints to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and followed your suggestion. Now the contenview hugs the editor view and it's centered in the scrollview which was unexpected. At least it's a little closer.